# Const-correct way to tell a function how to access required data from an arbitrary data structure?

Tags: c++11, lambda, constants, decltype

In this game of life program the user tells the solve function how to access required data. Is it possible to be const-correct inside the function without supplying it with both const and non-const versions of data accessors? Clang complains about the constness of neighbor cell data when checking whether neighbors are alive or not (candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const Cell') would lose const qualifier):

```
#include "array"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
struct Cell {
    bool is_alive = false; int nr_live_neighs = 0;
};

template<
    class Grid,
    class Is_Alive_Getter,
    class Nr_Live_Neighs_Getter
> void solve(
    Grid& grid,
    Is_Alive_Getter Is_Alive,
    Nr_Live_Neighs_Getter Nr_Live_Neighs
) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < grid.size() - 1; i++) {
        auto& cell = grid[i];
        const auto // how to stay const-correct here?
            &neigh_neg = grid[i - 1],
            &neigh_pos = grid[i + 1];
        if (Is_Alive(neigh_neg)) Nr_Live_Neighs(cell)++;
        if (Is_Alive(neigh_pos)) Nr_Live_Neighs(cell)++;
    }
    for (auto& cell: grid) {
        if (Nr_Live_Neighs(cell) == 3)
            Is_Alive(cell) = true;
        else if (Nr_Live_Neighs(cell) != 2)
            Is_Alive(cell) = false;
        Nr_Live_Neighs(cell) = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<Cell, 10> grid;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
        grid[i].is_alive = (i % 4 > 0);
    }

    solve(
        grid,
        [](Cell& cell_data) -> bool& {
            return cell_data.is_alive;
        },
        [](Cell& cell_data) -> int& {
            return cell_data.nr_live_neighs;
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

I can use

```
if (Is_Alive(const_cast<decltype(cell)>(neigh_neg)))
```

instead of

```
if (Is_Alive(neigh_neg))
```

inside the solver but that feels hacky even though it doesn't seem to affect time to solution. What if a non-const reference isn't available to use in decltype? Is there a generic way to cast away the const by only referring to the const variable?

Comment: why would you create a const ref to an object, that is not inherently const, only to then cast the constness away?. The real problem is probably, that `Is_Alive` should take a const reference.

Comment: Because then the second loop would fail when every cells' is_alive is updated.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked that. But my first point remains: There is just no reason to create a const reference here, when you want to use it as an input for a non-const reference parameter.

Comment: I guess that's the best solution, otherwise the code will get difficult to read and non-const references slow down the code less than 5 %.